# Hibernate cannot determine dialect

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee-7

I am using hibernate 4.3.x to connect to oracle database.

However while creating mapping file it throws

> "Unable to determine Dialect to use [ name = Oracle , majorVersion =
>   12 ]..."

which should be problem ( according to google ) in hiberante 3.x

How can i fix this? 
Thanks

//edit

Config properties:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:...</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">name</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">Passwd</property>
    <mapping class="Nemocnica" package="Model"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that there is an issue with hibernate detecting Oracle 12 dialect.

Use:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
```

Oracle 10 dialect should work with Oracle 12 also.

Comment: i added it to the config and error remains the same

Comment: Can you post your code files, I'll see if I can replicate the problem on my system.

Comment: Fixed the error , i had typo in the code u wrote, it works now thanks